# renjin as.Date(character,format) giving the wrong date?

Tags: r, renjin

I'm looking at using renjin 0.8.2124 to run some scripts within a JVM and I'm seeing different behavior between rJava/R and renjin with respect to parsing dates. In renjin-studio:

```
> print( as.Date( '2016.06.17', format = '%Y.%m.%d' ) )
[1] "2016-06-16"
```

Where as R:

```
> print( as.Date( '2016.06.17', format = '%Y.%m.%d' ) )
[1] "2016-06-17"
```

Why is renjin-studio subtracting a day from the date? I've checked the locale and timezone settings, and everything seems to match.

Comment: This is indeed a difference in behavior between Renjin and GNU R. An issue has been opened to address this: https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/199

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that this behavior is incorrect and it has now been fixed. See https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/199.